# Better displacement finder? Lasers/Inertial Sensors

Tags: measurement, laser, distance, motion

I've seen laser rpm measurement devices. But can it be used the find displacement/distance moved for object when attached to it?
I know taking rpm of wheel and multiplying by circumference would give it, but is there any way we can find distance moved when the object slides?
For example, a model roller-coaster, when its moves what is the best way to find its displacement? I find inertial sensors complex and less feasible.

Comment: Why not GPS based?

Comment: @Andy aka  I want to measure at small distances like..total 5 metres in area. So GPS no good

Comment: Video camera and reference circles? White with black cross like those seen on crash dummies?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your setup exactly. Does it slide on the surface in one or two dimensions? What is the surface? Can you attach things to said surface? How fast does the object move? Differential GPS has sub-millimeter repeatability btw.

Comment: @user110971 It is a small rollercoaster track which takes space less than 5 m² in area. The track is a all around lifted in the area. Can something attached to the coaster would help me track how much the coaster moved?

Comment: @user262839 Oh, that sort of coaster, not a drinks coaster. What distance resolution do you need? Do you want the distance along the track or (x, y, z) measurements? Does the coaster have its own motor or does it truly coast all the way round?

Comment: @user262839 I'm thinking that perhaps you could use the tracks as a variable resistor.

Comment: A linear encoder pattern  on the track would do the trick. Think of an audio track in old  films, printed in a pattern where an encoder or camera will be able to identify based on latter  where on the track you are, perhaps up to an offset that can be resolved with other sensors.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I only want distance along the track.  Coaster doesn't use motors, well it does have small bearing wheels and slides down and then up with gravitational force.

Comment: @user262839 If you can arrange the coaster such that one pair of wheels on an axle is electrically connnected, and no others, and that the track is electrically conductive (hopefully not very well, e.g. it might be made of thin steel) along its length, and not connected at the start/finish line, can you measure a difference in the resistance across the tracks between when the coaster is at the start and when the coaster is two-thirds of the way along?

Comment: For what its worth: My bicycle odometer (uses a magnetic reed switch on the front wheel) gives at most 0.1km error after a 100 km ride. That's hard to beat. I can even tell when my tire needs more air. This wheel-rotation sensor system is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Inertial devices imply an open loop control and all the challenges there. To have closed loop you need a true track position sensor,
Or perhaps more accurately, a true displacement sensor which can be achieved in several ways, e.g. a dummy wheel and rotational encoder, pressure switches to correct inertial tracking, or a track based linear encoder.

Linear encoders use specifically crafted marks that will allow you to determine where on the track you are, some require constant monitoring, that is, they are not absolute measurements but even with this you will be observing real position movement and thus have your closed loop

A wheel with rotary encoder running on the track will also work and simplify the track construction, but could be prone to slipping and same types of errors as inertial systems, a linear encoder on the track can tell you exactly where you are assuming you have been watching it all along.

Comment: I cannot use rotary encoders, because they are small and free rotating bearing wheels.  What other type of linear encoders can I use?

Comment: @user262839 your restriction doesn't make sense. Plenty of rotary encoders are available with free rotating wheels. Or you could add an additional wheel (as mentioned in this answer) with an encoder purely for the purpose of tracking position.

Comment: You could even use the ties supporting the track as a kind of encoder. Point an LED and photosensor down from the bottom of the carriage to the ties, and count how many times the reflection flickers as the carriage moves.